# Magento 2. How to override List.phtml

Tags: magento2, frontend, list.phtml

I want to Override **List.phtml** and for that I'm using this **Layout**

> Vender/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Vender_Module::product/list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I also create the custom **list.phtml** and **ListProduct.php** in my Module but after that still my module is not running my **list.phtml** its running its own **list.phtml**. What is the problem and how can I solve that Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the code is adding a new block in the content area not overriding any phtml file.

Replace the code with the following code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vender_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-override-phtml-file-custom-module/)

Comment: setTemplate is a deprecated method. Should avoid to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code with the following code

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

**Using New method**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vender_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vender_Module::product/list.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache

Comment: Can you please help me sir? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322616/74047