# Magento 2 : How to set different list.phtml for each category

Tags: magento2, category, layout

I want to do like this list.phtml should be different different call in category page. I created custom category layout and assign phtml file for that. But, layered navigation at bottom after product grid.

It should be display same as like 2-column-left layout. How to solve it?

**custom layout code :**

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/CustomTheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/category_my_custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
  <update handle="2columns-left"/>
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="category.products">
        <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/book_list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</layout>
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If only one category needs being customised, the easiest implementation is to create a specific layout file like below:

If we take a category that has the id 12, then create a specific layout file called `catalog_category_view_id_12.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mbs_ProductList::product/list_category12.phtml"</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you need something more flexible, you may look at the backend, the above layout customisation can be applied from the backend using `Layout Update XML` category textarea input under `Design` tab.

see screenshot below:
[image]

and finally, if you want to have hands on your layout name, best is to create a plugin for the product list `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Comment: Thank you for reply Herve. But, there are no field available like Layout Update XML in M235.

Comment: I have 10 different categories and there are 5 different design. Could you please guide me?

Comment: go to Magento Backend, edit a category, find the tab called Design and then you should see this design tab (once it opened) looks like my screenshot.

Comment: It's remove functionality in 2.3.5 version.

Comment: since you only have a small number of category, I'd go for specific layout files. UNless you are versatile with plugin

Comment: Okay. @Herve. One more question. Could you please guide me how to manage with custom layout file? It's almost done same as with updated code in question. But, layered navigation not proper display using that code.

Comment: If i will go with that code with solution then, I don't need to create too much files. Just need to assign that custom layout in category. Please help me.